# The declaration of this function

Tags: c, function-pointers, declaration

how to explain this right

```
char*(*a)(int, int);
```

just explain what does this declaration means. I'm not sure how to explain it right.
Thank you very much!

Comment: https://cdecl.org/ is your friend when it comes to parsing weird syntax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a` is a pointer to a function with two parameters of type `int` that returns a `char*`.

[The ``Clockwise/Spiral Rule''](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)

[cdecl: C gibberish ↔ English](https://cdecl.org/?q=char*%28*a%29%28int%2C+int%29)

Answer (score 3):

Like this: `a` is a pointer to function that accepts two `int` parameters and returns pointer to `char`.

Answer (score 1):

To make this declaration

```
char*(*a)(int, int);
```

clear use a typedef. For example

```
typedef char * FunctionType( int, int );

FunctionType *a;
```

That is `a` is a pointer to the function type `char * ( int, int )`.